# ¿Como manipular un Jbotton, un Jlabel y un JtextField desde otra clase?

Tags: java, poo

Pues tengo una pregunta que quizá sea fácil de resolver, pero es algo que yo aún no se,
resulta que tengo jframe con un jbutton,  un Jlabel y un JtextField, los cuales son invisibles, la cuestión es que en otra clase tengo una función, y quiero que esa función los haga visibles la momento de ejecutarla.

ejemplo, si esa función estaría en el mismo Jframe que están mi botón, mi label y mi textfield haría esto:

```
  Contraseña_nueva.setVisible(true);
  su_contraseña_es.setVisible(true);
  btn_aceptar.setVisible(true);
```

Obviamente como esta función esta en otra clase no reconoce ni  Contraseña_nueva, su_contraseña_es ni btn_aceptar, Quiero saber como puedo manipular estos 3 elementos desde otra clase que no sea el mismo jframe.
Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Bienvenido, ¿pero te ha dado algún error o no sabes cómo llamar a una variable desde otra clase? ¿has intentado a escribir la clase y luego la variable? Es decir: Clase.variable...

Comment: Si, intente de la siguiente manera
portal p = new portal()
P.newpass.setvisible(true);
pero no dio resultado

Comment: Si estás utilizando POO, programación orientada a objetos, deberías crear un objeto de dicha clase. Clase1 c1=new Clase1(); para poder así poder acceder a dicha clase.

Comment: Es que si puedo acceder a la clase, esa clase la activo con un botón
solo quiero que una de las funciones de esa clase sea poder activa un botón
una caja de texto y un label

Answer (score 1):

La forma más sencilla para acceder a una variable o un método de otra clase es con los métodos **get/set**, o en otro caso, método **toString()**.

```
public class Clase1{
   private String var1;

   public void setVar1(String var1){
      this.var1=var1;
   }

   public String getVar1(){
      return this.var1;
   }

   public void modificarValorVar1(){
      this.var1 = "cambiado valor de var1";
   }
}


public class Clase2{
   public static void main(String[] args){
   //Creamos un objeto de la clase Clase1 llamado "c1".
   Clase1 c1=new Clase1();
   c1.modificarValorVar1();
   String valorVar1=c1.getVar1();
   System.out.print(valorVar1);
   }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias,
la cosa es que no estoy intentando acceder a ninguna variable
lo que quiero básicamente es hacer visibles los elementos de un Jframe pero desde otra clase

Answer (score 0):

Si llamamos `Class1` tu clase de tipo `JFrame` y `Class2` la clase que define la función, entonces sería algo así:

### Class1

```
public class Class1 {
    private JButton btn_aceptar;

    //Crea un metodo público para cambiar el valór de tu campo privado
    public void setButtonVisible(boolean value) {
        btn_aceptar.setVisible(value);
    }
}
```

### Class2

```
public class Class2 {

    private Class1 class1; //Asumiendo que sea un membro de tu clase

    public void setButtonVisible() {
        class1.setButtonVisible(true);
    }
}
```

En esta clase, la variable `class1` es tu instancia de `Class1` por la cual quieres hacer visible el botón.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo he conseguido de la siguiente manera:
Pongo en public y static el botón y el textfield como se muestra en la imagen, y desde la clase que los deseo activar únicamente uso el siguiente código:
     PortalDunosusa.aceptar_pass.setVisible(true);
Siendo que PortalDunosusa es el nombre del Jframe donde se encuentran,
aceptar_pass es el nombre del botón y setVisible(true) la función que los hace visibles al momento de ejecutar esa función.